# My meta profile's "website field" does not sync with my main profile

Tags: support, bug, profile-sync

I created my profile on SO and synced it with my other accounts. It worked fine except my website.

I changed my website on SO and it got synced to all accounts except my **meta SO** account.

How do I sync my meta profile?

Why does it not sync automatically. Is this the way it is supposed to be or its a bug?